# Minecraft: Increase Redstone Signal Without Delay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to increase (repeat) the signal of redstone, as the signal can only travel for 15 blocks without repeat, however using repeaters is not the solution, as repeaters have 1 tick of delay, which is troubling for some creations. The only other solution I saw was to make a double NOT gate with redstone torches, which still caused delay on the repeated side.

Comment: Another solution is to run the redstone into a block with a torch on the other side, then again further down the line.

Comment: @WillB. I tried that, but torches seem to have delay of about 0.5 tick, because when I did that, I did get delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For repeating a redstone signal without delay, you should build an instant repeater as such:

[image: Instant repeater]
(Both pistons are sticky pistons)

Comment: +1, anyway, won't the piston's push time play a role in the delay?

Comment: @JohnSmith It shouldn't; you can see an explanation of it [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Transmission_circuit#Instant_repeater).

Comment: I see.... Accepted the answer, thx. However not (yet) a problem, when the input signal activates and deactivates quickly, the repeater stays active